# Android App has been working for weeks and now it fails every time to Launch

Tags: android

I have been working on my Android application for weeks now and suddenly it just will not launch.  I get the same errors on my mobile device as well as on the Emulator.  I have made backups of older versions off my application as I go along, and despite reloading these into eclipse I am still getting the same  errors. I really do not understand and panicking. Please can someone advise?

My stacktrace:

```
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573): Process: com.example.lifesci_pubmed, PID: 6573
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.example.lifesci_pubmed/com.android.lifesci_pubmed.ArticleListFragment_developActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.ArticleListFragment_develop.recallToReadList(ArticleListFragment_develop.java:685)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.ArticleListFragment_develop.onCreate(ArticleListFragment_develop.java:91)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1481)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:908)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:571)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1194)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5258)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2171)
11-20 11:46:29.821: E/AndroidRuntime(6573):     ... 11 more
11-20 11:51:29.848: I/Process(6573): Sending signal. PID: 6573 SIG: 9
```

Comment: What is line number 685 in ArticleListFragment_develop.java , probably in a function recallToReadList

Comment: can you write a "Hello World"  and then run?

Comment: please write your code...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have declared the activitys in the manifest?